# Jquery click then hide not working

Tags: jquery, html

I have used the following basic jquery hide script many times. But for some reason it isn't working this time. Any suggestions would be valued. Please note the things i have tried below.

```
$('#jobrequest-open').click(function(){

    alert("test");
    $(".test").hide();

});


<button id="jobrequest-open" class="btn btn-block btn-info">Job Requestor 
Submission</button>
```

In this application the alert button opens OK (so click is registered by the JScript) but the div does not hide.

So I removed the click event listener and just loaded

```
alert("test");
$(".test").hide();
```

Sure enough the alert pops up and the element hides as expected.

I have tried event.stopPropagation(); before the alert obviously adding (event) to the function. No effect.

I have tried the `$(document).ready(function()` wrapper - again no effect. So at a bit of a loss. Cant find any prior Q/A that addresses this kinda weird issue.

ps..This bit of script is running with pluploader plug in - not thinking that should be an issue though.

Comment: Wheres the element with the test class?

Comment: did you have an element with `class=".test"`?

Comment: yes it a long form div so i didn't post it. Bear in mind the div hides when the click function is stripped from the js.

Comment: Abe - the div wouldnt hide if i hadn't got the .test class attached. It does hide but not when the click event is wrapping the js code. Although weirdly the alert does pop up. So the click is registered

Comment: A further bit of info. I tried removing the div contents altogether and just put <h4> STUFF</H4> inside the class .test div. Same problem.

Comment: @user2755309 can you show us the html.. just the structure.. not all the data.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the CSS related to the class `.test` is not set to something like:

```
.test {
    display: block!important;
}
```

The example of how it is:

```js
$('#jobrequest-open').click(function(){

    alert("test");
    $(".test").hide();

});
```

```css
.test {
 display: block!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
diz me
</div>


<button id="jobrequest-open" class="btn btn-block btn-info">Job Requestor 
Submission</button>
```

And the example of how it works:

```js
$('#jobrequest-open').click(function(){

    alert("test");
    $(".test").hide();

});
```

```css
.test {
 /* Nothing */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
diz me
</div>


<button id="jobrequest-open" class="btn btn-block btn-info">Job Requestor 
Submission</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I think you might be on something like the right track because have stripped out everything as you have done above and it works fine standalone. But when I copy the same code back into my script i get the weird affect described. For info - I think the hide event is actually happening But somewhere in my script the div is somehow being re-rendered. (There is no css assigned to .test)

Comment: After clicking, use inspect element to view the HTML of your `.test` element. If its inline CSS is `style="display: none;"` then your function is working fine and no new element is created and the problem is coming from CSS. If not, then there's a new element created.

Comment: The problem was found - but a handy tip for anyone reading this Duc. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that `alert("test")` blocks every process running on window, so the div will not hide until you have closed the alert.

You could avoid this by putting `alert` into a callback:

```
$('#jobrequest-open').click( function(){

    $(".test").hide(50, function(){
        // This function will trigger AFTER the hide animation
        alert("test");

        });

    });
```

Comment: Thanks kidkamek. I did try this and it didnt work. I only added the alert after the hide event failed. Just to see if i was getting inside the js click script , Interestingly though the alert fails to work in the configuration you supplied-whereas the alert does pop up prior to the hide() event. Hmmm so the .hide() bit is actually blocking your alert function for some strange reason.

Comment: Oh... that throws new clues into the problem... The only reason i know the alert could fail to trigger is that there is no element with `class = "test"` and, because or that, the `hide()` animation is not triggered at all (and, of course its callback is not triggered also)... Is your div declared like this: `<div class = "test">`?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a modern version try this because in new versions this way for writing events is deprecated

```js
$('button').on('click', function () {
  $('.test').hide(50, function () {
    alert('Some Text');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Jop-Request</button>
<div class="test">Some Text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your help. There was no direct answer but the clues were in the various responses. My problem was not the js. My problem was where the trigger button resided within the context of the overall script. I had the btn inside a form tag. I am a fool not spotting that a little earlier but hopefully someone will benefit - if they put a hide() - or any other js render type trigger button -
 inside a form tag.

Comment: I'm glad you solved the problem... as a recommendation: you should write the most complete html structure and code into your question so everyone could test and replicate the problem. You can start by editing your question with the html example that doesnt work and your answer with the working code and html structure

Comment: Fair point kidamek. I figured it couldn't be the html - and that was rather silly of me! Thanks for your help.